# populating three follow up select lists using php+mysql and jquery ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok I've chainged script, this is now the code of index file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){              

        jQuery("select[name='brand']").change(function(){               

            var brandValue = jQuery("select[name='brand']").val();     

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "handler.php",
                data: ({brand: brandValue, status: 1}),
                beforeSend: function(){ jQuery("#loader").show(); },
                complete: function(){ jQuery("#loader").hide(); },
                success: function(response){
                    jQuery("#results").html(response);
                    jQuery("#results").show();
                }
            });         
        });

        jQuery('body').on('change','select[name="series"]',function(){               

            var seriesValue = jQuery("select[name='series']").val();
            var brandValue = jQuery("select[name='brand']").val();     

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "handler.php",
                data: ({series: seriesValue, brand: brandValue, status: 1}),
                beforeSend: function(){ jQuery("#loader").show(); },
                complete: function(){ jQuery("#loader").hide(); },
                success: function(response){
                    jQuery("#results").html(response);
                    jQuery("#results").show();
                }
            });         
        });

        jQuery('body').on('change','select[name="models"]',function(){               

            var modelsValue = jQuery("select[name='models']").val();
            var seriesValue = jQuery("select[name='series']").val();
            var brandValue = jQuery("select[name='brand']").val();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "handler.php",
                data: ({models: modelsValue, series: seriesValue, brand: brandValue, status: 1}),
                beforeSend: function(){ jQuery("#loader").show(); },
                complete: function(){ jQuery("#loader").hide(); },
                success: function(response){
                    jQuery("#results").html(response);
                    jQuery("#results").show();
                }
            });         
        });

    });
</script>

Brands: 
<select name="brand">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
<?php
$brands = get_brands();
foreach($brands as $brand) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $brand['brand_id']?>"><?php echo $brand['brand_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>

<div id="results" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading..."></div>
```

and this is procesing file:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['brand'])) {
    $curentSeries = get_series($_POST['brand']);
    ?>

    Series: 
    <select name="series">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <?php
        foreach($curentSeries as $ser) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ser['series_id']; ?>"><?php echo $ser['series_name']; ?></option>
            <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
?>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['series'])) {
    $curentModels = get_models($_POST['brand'], $_POST['series']);
    ?>

    Model: 
    <select name="models">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <?php
        foreach($curentModels as $model) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $model['model_id']; ?>"><?php echo $model['model_name']; ?></option>
            <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
?>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['models'])) {
    echo "<br />brand: {$_POST['brand']}<br />series: {$_POST['series']}<br />model: {$_POST['models']}";
}
```

script is working now, we figured it out, final issue was in the processing file, as i sorted it out, all is fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your 'series' data is created dynamically , you need to use 'on' event in jquery.Check following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){              

    jQuery("select[name='brand']").change(function(){               

        var optionValue = jQuery("select[name='brand']").val();     

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: ({brand: optionValue, status: 1}),
            beforeSend: function(){ jQuery("#loader").show(); },
            complete: function(){ jQuery("#loader").hide(); },
            success: function(response){
                jQuery("#series").html(response);
                jQuery("#series").show();
            }
        });         
    });

    jQuery('body').on('change','select[name="series"]',function(){               

        var seriesValue = jQuery("select[name='series']").val();     

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: ({series: seriesValue, status: 1}),
            beforeSend: function(){ jQuery("#loader").show(); },
            complete: function(){ jQuery("#loader").hide(); },
            success: function(response){
                jQuery("#model").html(response);
                jQuery("#model").show();
            }
        });         
    });

     });
  </script>
```

Comment: stuff seems to be working i just got one question why we are binding this `jQuery('body').on('change','select[name="series"]',function(){` to `body` is this how it should be done? i just dont know jquery well so i would like to know if its good practice and legit solution if it is i will be sure to follow :)

Comment: You are telling the jquery that there is a dynamic change in the 'body' - like there is some new elements created, so jquery creates events based on the newly created html elements.You can even narrow down to the part where the select box is loaded (id="model"). For more info refer this https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Comment: @user2668182 I believe this answer deserves your vote !

Comment: i have updated my primary question at the top of the page, please help me figure out what is wrong with the code now;)

Comment: change this jQuery("#results").html(response); to jQuery("#results").append(response);

Comment: in some way it helped, now passing data is working and all stuff, but as you can see now if you enter file again, its duplicating over and over

Comment: OK leave as jQuery("#results").html(response); but instead of using the same "results" id try to load in different ids

Comment: done that, still seems to be duplicating, crap dont know how to handle it ;d

Comment: now the problem is in your procesing file (php file). Check your ajax response in your browser console using Mozilla firebug. You are sending the select box two times

Comment: ok i figured it out, thank you for all the help :) you are very resourceful programmer mate :)